# Heroku. Django dumpdata

Tags: django, heroku

How can I get the data on Heroku and create a fixture I can load locally? `heroku run python manage.py dumpdata --natural > data.json` is the command, but how can I download the file?

Comment: What operating system and shell are you using? For me (on Mac OS X), redirecting the output creates a local file.

Comment: @DanielHepper I'm on Ubuntu. Bash.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding to dashes to indicate the end of the command:

```
heroku run python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign -- > data.json
```

This should redirect the output to a local file.

Comment: Note that since 1.7 `--natural` is deprecated, use `--natural-foreign` instead

Comment: You sir are a goddamn hero.

Comment: On MacOS using Heroku CLI `8.7.1`, the trailing dashes caused issues. What worked for me was `heroku run -a <APP_NAME> -- python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign > data.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try `heroku pg:backups capture
$ curl -o latest.dump` - `heroku pg:backups public-url`